# Is my table the cause of my grouped barplots weird formating?

Tags: r

So I am very new to R, and am not very sure what my problem is.

So my data looks something like this:

```
|Time  | Gender | School |
|:-----|:-------|:-------|
|44    |   m    | SB     |
|57    |   m    | DN     |
|53    |   m    | K      |
|48    |   m    | N      |
|45    |   f    | SB     |
|50    |   f    | DN     |
|49    |   f    | K      |
|43    |   f    | N      |
```

I got this data in an `data.frame(run_data)`, where a lot more data is stored, this would be `run_data[9:16, ]`.

Now I want my barplot to use the time as an y-axis, and have the Schools grouped together (on the x-axis) with a bar for each gender.
I tried:

```
barplot(table(run_data[9:16, ]$Time, run_data[9:16, ]$School) beside=TRUE)
```

And School first, then time, both times I got a weird graph, where nothing was grouped, and the y-axis was 0-1.

I thought the problem was that the school column is a character column, so I changed it to an factor, and them numeric. When opened through `fix(run_data)` it had changed the names to 1, 2, 3, or 4, but when I used barplot, it was still the same weird thing.

This it what it looks like when Time is first:
[Time first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI3ZC.png)

And this when School is first:
[School first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvnm4.png)

My best guess is that the table is somehow wrong, but I am not sure how. Help would be great, and if possible with just basic R, it would be even greater. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you are asking for

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(Time=c(44,57,53,48,45,50,49,43),
                Gender=c('m', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'), 
                School=c('SB', 'DN', 'K', 'N', 'SB', 'DN' ,'K', 'N'))

ggplot(df, aes(x=School, y=Time, fill=Gender))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Edit: If you don't use `position_dodge`, it will stack them:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=School, y=Time, fill=Gender))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

If you don't use `fill`, it won't separate male and female:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=School, y=Time))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: This is how I want my end result to look like, but I just don't understand why R does not put the times from school A together automatically.
Like, if I have to time for school "A", I thought it would group them together without having to specify why there are two times. But it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant.  What is school A?

Comment: Can be any school. Like saying x in a formal. 

So, (for example) school DN. It has two times, so I thought that with barplot it would automatically put the times from DN together.

Comment: Oh ok. If you don't tell ggplot to use the Gender column in any way, it will ignore it and only use School and Time.  See above for what happens if you don't specifiy `fill`. There is no mention of Gender in the code, so ggplot plots the total Time for each School.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **base R** solution:

```
dat
#  Time Gender School
#1   44      m     SB
#2   57      m     DN
#3   53      m      K
#4   48      m      N
#5   45      f     SB
#6   50      f     DN
#7   49      f      K
#8   43      f      N

v <- dat$Time[order(dat$School)]
names(v) <- dat$School[order(dat$School)]
v_mf <- dat$Gender[order(dat$School)]
v_mf[ v_mf == "m" ] <- "blue2"
v_mf[ v_mf == "f" ] <- "red2"

barplot( v, border=F, col=v_mf,
         space=rep( c(1,0),length(unique(dat$School)) ),
         legend=dat$Gender[order(dat$School)][1:2] )
```

[image]

You can add more features to the plot, like a title, axis lables etc within `barplot()`.

Answer (score 0):

The formula interface to the base R generic `barplot` is very simple to use.

```
barplot(
  formula = Time ~ ., 
  data = run_data, 
  beside = TRUE, 
  col = c("blue", "red"),
  legend.text = c("f", "m")
)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
run_data <-
structure(list(Time = c(44, 57, 53, 48, 45, 50, 49, 43), Gender = c("m", 
"m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f"), School = c("SB", "DN", "K", 
"N", "SB", "DN", "K", "N")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```